# Aligning of modal box

Tags: css, alignment

I am trying to align the modal box ( in this case it's a confirm box ) in the center of the page. So I set the position of the main container to be relative and then positioned the div element of the modal box using the following **CSS** code:

```
.confirmBox{
    top:25%;
    left:25%;
}
```

I have adjusted the values of the **top** and **left** attributes. This works fine at lower zoom but as I zoom in the box does not remain in the center of the page. How can I solve this using CSS?

The original code is actually big and i am not able to think of an instance for this case.
Still I am considering the div element with class="confirmBox" to be the code for confirmBox and attaching the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/47/.

Comment: Can you post up some code? JSFiddle or in-context?

Comment: Here is the fiddle again.. http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/47/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 50% left and top positions, and then subtract half of the width and height to make up for the size of the element:

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
height: <your value>px;
margin-top: (negative value of your height, divided by 2);
width:<your value>px;
left:50%;
margin-left: (negative value of your width, divided by 2);
```

I think this way is easier to understand. If the width of the element is 40% (of its container), then it should be 30% to the left to be equally centered:

`|-----30%-----|-------40%--------|-----30%-----|`

which all == 100%

**Or**

you can use % width and % height, and use simple math to figure out the left and top positioning:

```
position:absolute;
height:40%;
width:40%;
left:30%; // (100 - width) divided by 2
top:30%; // (100 - height) divided by 2
```

Comment: iight... please have a look at the fiddle. and observe the behaviour on zooming in.

Comment: you can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/48/
or http://jsfiddle.net/W6ATN/49/ both similar to my answer. once uses % one uses margin.

Comment: Thats what i wanted. Can you give me any link so that i can understand what is happening behind the curtain..

Comment: Best way is google or find something on `CSS` and positioning. JSfiddle will be great to understand the differences and you'll be able to experiment yourself. Or, use google chrome and push CTRL+SHIFT+C. This will bring up the developer toolbar, you can then click on an element and adjust the CSS in realtime! (i.e. change things in the toolbar and watch the page change.) or: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
// Slightly modified custom css with all due credit to it's previous owner  
//
//           @@ Cat...

.vertical-align-center {

left: 0%; // <<<------ Align left and comfortably stretch across the screen
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle pointer-events: none;
}
```